Ubuntu 24.04 LTS virtual. I've difficulty installing python related packages ? example i'm providing code below?
while I'm installing a specific tool related to pentesting I encountered following problem in my ubuntu terminal it showing This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.
not only this time this happened each and everytime when I was trying to install python packaged tools I'm encountering this problem. somepne please look into these issue.
                   This APT has Super Cow Powers.
david@david:~/Desktop$ git clone https://github.com/guelfoweb/knock.git
Cloning into 'knock'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1615, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (179/179), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (94/94), done.
remote: Total 1615 (delta 93), reused 136 (delta 76), pack-reused 1436 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (1615/1615), 542.32 KiB | 122.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (744/744), done.
david@david:~/Desktop$ cd knock
david@david:~/Desktop/knock$ pip install .
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
david@david:~/Desktop/knock$ 


Pehaps this would be simpler https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/knockpy - see also pip error on Ubuntu: externally-managed-environment × This environment is externally managed

Your wording in the question makes it very hard to follow.

... yeah the only wrinkle here seems to be that the equivalent apt package is not named like python3-xyz, but like xyzpy

how can I reslove those issue ?

@david9240 make sure you have enabled the "universe" repository in your sources, then sudo apt update and sudo apt install knockpy

This question can be closed. as my problem has been resolved.
